# Navigation Drawer Item Selected Listeners Not Working (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

Following on from my previous question ([Open Navigation Drawer from Button Click within Fragment (Kotlin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262106/open-navigation-drawer-from-button-click-within-fragment-kotlin)), I have successfully created a custom button which, when clicked, opens a Navigation Drawer.

I am now trying to hook up the buttons to do things, but I can't even manage to get them to fire a toast:

**Activity** (I have implemented NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

```js
class SiteActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)
        setContentView(R.layout.site_activity)
        
        siteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SiteViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(this)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(this)
    }

    override fun onAuthStateChanged(firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth) {

        // Will only fire if state has changed!

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser == null) {
            makeToast("User logged out")
            goToLoginActivity()
            return
        }
    }

    private fun goToLoginActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }


    fun openCloseNavigationDrawer() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            drawer_layout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
    
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_first_fragment -> makeToast("Button Clicked")
            R.id.nav_second_fragment -> makeToast("Button Clicked")

        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

    private fun makeToast(message: String) {

        val centeredText: Spannable = SpannableString(message)
        centeredText.setSpan(
            AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER),
            0, message.length - 1,
            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
        )

        val toast = Toast.makeText(this, centeredText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0)
        toast.show()
        Log.d(TAG, "Toast message: $message")
    }

}
```

Here is where I expected something to happen (note, makeToast is just my own method to create a centered Toast message which I know works):

```
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_first_fragment -> makeToast("Button Clicked")
        R.id.nav_second_fragment -> makeToast("Button Clicked")

    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

The drawer opens ok and the button is clickable, but no toast and the drawer stays open when you click the button.

**site_actvity.xml** and **drawer_menu.xml** are shown fully in previous post, but I can add if this helps..

Comment: initialise the listener with `setNavigationItemSelectedListener `

Comment: How did you initialize your Navigation Drawer and listener? Can you add more details of `SiteActivity`?

Comment: Hi both, I have updated question to show full Activity..  Can you confirm where I should initialise the listener please?..

Comment: @Scamparelli, Check question and answer there and follow that.

Comment: Sorry - away from desk.  Let me digest and I will do so ASAP..

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman thank you again - I have checked question on your link.  It worked with just setNavigationItemSelectedListener, but I don't know why you need the nv_top.setupWithNavController(navController) element..?