# (Android) Is there any way to make a button in the fragment open the drawerlayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, drawerlayout, android-viewbinding

I clicked a new android kotlin project "Navigation Drawer Activity" in default templates, the android studio. And I made a splash screen in the project with SplashScreen API. I want to delete the toolbar on the upper side and add a button in HomeFragment to open the drawerlayout.

[activity_main.xml(MainActivity.kt)] -<include />→ [app_bar_main.xml] -<include />→ [content_main.xml] -<fragment />→ [fragment_home.xml(HomeFragment.kt)] -<ImageButton />→ android:id="@+id/buttonOpenDrawerLayout"

activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried on HomeFragment.kt:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root

    val drawerLayout = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).drawerLayout //@PointA
    binding.buttonOpenDrawerLayout.setOnClickListener {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)
    } //@PointB
    return root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
}
```

but failed. The application stopped on the splash screen and logcat says:

```
D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
D/EgretLoader: The context is not activity
D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
D/EgretLoader: The context is not activity
......
```

I moved @PointA and @PointB to onStart() or onResume() but also failed. I changed @PointA to:

```
val drawerLayout = view?.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) as DrawerLayout
```

but NullPointerException. Also, After I erased @PointA and @PointB, I tried on MainActivity.kt:

```
// onCreate()
FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).buttonOpenDrawerLayout.setOnClickListener {
        ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)
}
```

Nothing errors occured but nothing happened when I clicked the button. Could you tell me how can I made the button open the drawerlayout?

Comment: Use shared view model and trigger a an event and then observe in activity.

Comment: you can user interface to close and open a drawer or you can use activity instance directly in fragment like (activity as MainActivity).openDrawer() something like this.

Comment: rahat, gulabpatel thanks. I solved it by android:onClick - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262106/open-navigation-drawer-from-button-click-within-fragment-kotlin